# How to get items to be displayed in left navigation pane of windows explorer

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, explorer, windows-shell, win32com

I need to get all the items in the left navigation pane of windows explorer.Same as a new explorer window would display i.e. taking into account the user settings.

i am not getting any API or registry where i can get these settings.

I can get the details of these folder (Favorites, Libraries, Network etc. )  in general using IKnownFolderManager and IKnownFolder COM interfaces.
But my problem is i only want to get the items which user has enabled/customized to display in explorer. where these explorer settings are saved ?

please suggest any Win32/COM API or any other programmable way to get this done.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with the desktop using `SHGetDesktopFolder`, enumerate it using `IShellFolder::EnumObjects`, recurse into sub-folders with `BindToObject`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter doesn't this get only folder contents on file system, not those on the left panel where it says "Libraries", "Documents", "Pictures" and you can expand any of them?

Comment: Nope, those calls are for enumerating the [shell namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [windows libraries api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).